# Was game theory used during World War II?

Tags: world-war-two, mathematics

The mathematical theory of [game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) is about finding optimal srategies for games such as [rock-paper-scissors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_paper_scissors).
I have heard it claimed several times that game theory was used during World War II by the Americans to decide military strategies but I am unable to find any reliable source, except for [some](https://blogs.cornell.edu/info2040/2016/09/16/game-theory-in-world-war-2/) that model the situation *afterwards*.

> Was game theory really used by the HQ or was the situation just left to the gut feeling of the commanders?

I am interested in concrete game theoretic modeling of military situations based on which decision was made, in any war. To be more specific, I mean that a mathematical model was made based on some available options, and the option executed in reality was decided by randomly selecting one of the options, based on the optimal mixed strategy.

Comment: You are asking about game theory in specific, and not operations research in more general terms?

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly. Germans had  table "war game" (Kriegsspiel) from 19th century, it spread around the world. However, war is not a simple game, many factors are involved and it is not simple to emulate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriegsspiel

Comment: @rs.29, while war game was called a game and could have a referee, it does not strictly use game theory in the sense of mathematics.

Comment: @o.m. True, but it is a precursor of modern computer war games, with formalized algorithmic rules for referee.

Comment: @rs.29, game theory has a very specific meaning, hence my initial comment. Not every insight drawn from games is a game theory.

Comment: Game theory, from Nash, dates from 1951.  It builds on earlier works, but the current theory most people think of when they hear "game theory" could not have been used in WW2.  Rock papers scissors has been used for millenia - archers, cavalry, pikemen, but is applied to **tactical** battlefield situations, not **strategic** planning.  Are you primarily asking about strategic analysis, operational planning or tactical battlefield management?

Comment: @o.m. You are partially wrong. Game theory is simply a study of certain mathematical models, that could be used for modeling games, but also modeling (simulating) certain events in real life. As such game theory did actually start BC , because people were interested in probabilities in gambling, but also in games like chess.

Comment: @Italian I don't think game theory dates from 1951, I would rather cite Neumann, 1928-1944, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_Games_and_Economic_Behavior. Also, in a link included in my original question, see the claim: "game theory has been heavily involved in decision making for battle plans during World War 2".

Comment: A related question is if game theory has been used to shed meaningful light on WW2. I've seen some post-war modeling (e.g. Japanese decision-making about the selection of convoy route in the Battle of the Bismark Sea) but those have struck me as being artificial. One problem in what you are asking is that in any real application, optimal strategies are probabilistic -- but it is unlikely that any commander would have literally randomized their decisions in the requisite way.

Comment: This [1954 paper by a former Air Force colonel](https://www.jstor.org/stable/166693) analyzes the way some generals took their decisions in actual WWII battles throught game theory. It is not waht you are asking for (9 years too late), but it‘s old enough to give a plausible source for the claim

Answer (score 1):

Game theory was indeed, developed around the time of World War II. The example generally cited is the dilemma facing American Air Force General [George Kenney](https://scholarworks.uni.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1097&context=pst) in New Guinea.

There were two east-west routes across New Guinea for Japanese convoys, the cloudy northern route, and the sunny southern route. A convoy used the southern route, one of two things would happen: The convoy would be destroyed if Kenney directed his planes that way, and unscathed if he chose to patrol the northern route.

A convoy using the northern route would be "damaged," but some were likely to survive if attacked. (Of course, they could be "unscathed" if Kenney patrolled the southern route.)

The Japanese opted for the northern route, "some damage, some survival" versus the all-or-nothing southern route. Anticipating this, Kenney patrolled the northern route. And the "saddle point" result of "some damage" was achieved.

A similar decision faced Eisenhower during the invasion of Italy. The two choices were Rome, and Salerno (southern Italy). In the latter location, fighter cover would ensure at least an American beachhead, even against German opposition. If the landing was at Rome, it would either shorten the Italian campaign by a year (capture Rome in 1943 instead of 1944 if unopposed), or be destroyed by German resistance with no fighter protection (a real setback).

Eisenhower opted for the safer choice (sure beachhead establishment, longer slog up the peninsula). Germany's "Smiling Albert" Kesselring anticipated this and pushed German forces to the south, mostly bypassing Rome along the way.

Comment: These more seem to fall in the category of minimizing worst-case loss rather than using a mixed strategy where the choice is made randomly, as in an optimal play of rock-paper-scissors. Also, I feel that these were choices left to the 'gut feeling of the commander.'

Comment: This answers the question "have game theorists used WWII as a source of examples" not "was game theory used during WWII"